# Test for target existence

Tags: scons

I have a SCons file which calls others to build different variants of a program.
Sadly a few of these variants (AKA lower SConscripts) need to build a library via invoking an external program.

```
# /SConstruct
<...>
subdirs = ['variant1', 'variant2', 'variant3']
for subdir in subdirs:
    SConscript(dirs=subdir, src_dir=subdir)

# /variant1/SConscript
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
<...>

# /variant2/SConscript
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
<...>
```

This gives the warnings:

```
scons: warning: Two different environments were specified for target ../libs/generated.so
                but they appear to have the same action: someexternalscript
```

Which is of course correct, but I don't know how I can check for a target's existence in the variant *SConscripts*.
And since others may call the SConscripts later on I cannot rely on global variables being present.

Comment: This isn't enough information to provide a reasonable answer, please add a minimal example that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know if you really regard the *../libs/generated.so* is a part of the build or not.

If this is a library you expect to exist outside of the build, but you want to make sure. I suggest you use the Configure to make sure that the library exist, and if not you might fail or run the someexternalscript to remedy the situation.

```
config = Configure(env)
if not config.CheckLib("generated.so") make_generated_so()
```

How you actually make_generated_so() depends on how you want to do it, you might make it a part of your build or just run the shell script during the config phase here.

If you on the other hand regard the ../libs/generated.so as a part of the build you must create this target once, and make the depending targets depend on this .so file you might do this by including the generated.so node as a part of targets in the `env.Program("someprogram",target)` or just do `env.Depends(sometarget,"generated.so")`

Comment: So in short, your answer is - you cannot check the existence globally by default. Fair enough.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "globally" but the `config.CheckLib()` checks of the existence of an available library. If this is false, the environment you have constructed in env is not able to detect a library.

Answer (score 0):

So, SConscript1 will build : ../libs/generated.so, and SConscript2 will build same ../libs/generated.so - same target file.

You can't use 2 same targets (../libs/generated.so in SConscript1 and SConscript2). You must specify different target for one of Command in SConscripts. For example for SConscript2 Command(../libs/generated2.so.

> but I don't know how I can check for a target's existence in the
>   variant SConscripts

Why you need to check it? If scons detects target need to build it would be build. You also can set additional dependecy for run Command to generate .so if any of source files would be changed.

```
genLibCmd = localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
Depends(genLibCmd, [ listOfSrcThatSomeExternalScriptUse ])
```

For test existing target you may use scons class File:

```
File('#libs/generated.so').exists()
```

But, i'm sure - you have wrong Sconscripts if you build same target twice.

Comment: You did not understand. I am NOT building the libraries. The external script, which I am not in control of does it. So you could regard *someexternalscript* as a black box - you put something in and get something out. And that is `../libs/generated.so`.

Comment: You are instructing SCons to call the external script, and thus are requesting that SCons builds the .so via the external script.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I do not clone the environment for this particular process. And I don't think you need to in your example, as that Command does not change anything in env. You can clone afterwards.
If this target ends up being called from different SConscripts, with their env already cloned, have a single environment accessible for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If this is literally the code, I see two ways to remove the warning:

```
# /SConstruct
<...>
subdirs = ['variant1', 'variant2', 'variant3']
for subdir in subdirs:
    SConscript(dirs=subdir, src_dir=subdir)

# /variant1/SConscript
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
<...>

# /variant2/SConscript
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
<...>
```

Also note, there really isn't two SConscripts (one in variant1, and one in variant2, its the same SConscript.

**First**: Call some externalscript before the clone:

```
# /variant*/SConscript
env.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
<...>
```

**Secondly**: add some conditional logic and pass a flag via SConscript call:

```
# /SConstruct
<...>
subdirs = ['variant1', 'variant2', 'variant3']
for subdir in subdirs:
    build_generated = (subdir == 'variant1')
    SConscript(dirs=subdir, src_dir=subdir, exports=['env','build_generated'])

# /variant*/SConscript
Import('build_generated','env')
localEnv = env.Clone() # Duplicates the global Environment so we may modify it without problems
if build_generated:
    localEnv.Command('../libs/generated.so', '', 'someexternalscript')
<...>
```

**Lastly**: if you always want this script called, you can put the call in SConstruct itself.

Additionally, why list the source for the target as ''?

That target will never changed, at the very least the source should be someexternalscript